# Question on replacing ceiling fan with light fixture

Tags: electrical

I took down my ceiling fan, and it looks like there was a white, yellow, and blue wire being used. 
The black wire I see capped and up in the junction box.

If I install just a simple light fixture, what wires would I expect to use ?

Is it odd that the black wire was not being used for the fan ?

Comment: _How_ were those wires being used? What's the switch situation?

Comment: Where are you in the world because the colors you mention mean way different things in the U.K. and US.

Comment: A picture of the wires in the fan junction box and a picture of the wires connected to the switch that controls the fan would help a lot.

Comment: This article will help you figure out what those wires are probably for: https://www.homedepot.com/c/ah/how-to-wire-a-ceiling-fan/